# How to get information from an installed malicious program?

Tags: windows, security, troubleshooting, logging

I asked a question today on security.stackexchange.com

[Hijacked certificate and Remote Login. Office computer compromised with a virus?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183545/hijacked-certificate-and-remote-login-compromised-our-work-computer-with-a-virus) which is a question about a suspicious program named PROGRAM.

I'd like to learn as much about this program as I can. When I try to get properties from this program it's greyed out.

[image: Screenshot of PROGRAM on Task Manager]

How can I gather more info about this program so I can better formulate a question on security.stackexchange?

What methods can be used to learn about a program and what it does?

Windows 10

UPDATE: I took the hard drive out of the computer and mounted it externally on a different computer. I've run a targeted scan with Avast antivirus and it says there are no viruses. This makes me very nervous because there is obviously a virus on the computer.

Comment: Does [Process Explorer](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip) give more info?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably an empty registry key in the Windows start-up "run" registry key. You can check in regedit and possibly delete it at `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]`

There should be a similar key under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` branch.

You can use [autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to find out exactly where this item is listed to start-up and what it is pointing at, if it is indeed trying to run anything.

Comment: It's definitely trying to do something malicious with remote login. I'll try this out and let you know what I find thanks